# Importing a C/C++ project programmatically eclipse

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Any help on how to import a C/C++ project programmatically using java into eclipse.

This is part of a plugin development, where an external tool creates all the files for a C++ project and my plugin should be able to import the project from that folder programmatically into the current workspace.

I have done the same for java, but unable to understand how to do it for C/C++

So here is so more clarity

- the .project file is not generated by the external tool
- when i manually import the folder into eclipse as "existing projects into workspace" eclipse doesnt create the .cproject and .project files
- but when i manually import it as "makefile project" then eclipse creates the .project and .cproject files in the project directory.

I have already acheived importing as existing project

by the code below

System.out.println("Opening CPP project");

```
    //IWorkspaceRoot wrkSpaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

    project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("ABCD");

    //String path="";
    try {

    //pMonitor.beginTask("creating CDT Project ", 0);

    IProjectDescription projDesc = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription(project.getName());

    if (!("".equals(projectPath)) && projectPath != null) {

    Path myPath = new Path(projectPath);
    projDesc.setLocation(myPath);

    }

    IProject cdtProj = CCorePlugin.getDefault().createCDTProject(
    projDesc, project, null);


    //if(create) cdtProj.create(projDesc, null);
    cdtProj.open(null);

    IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

    workbench.showPerspective("org.eclipse.cdt.ui.CPerspective", window);

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

what i want is to import the project as "makefile project" into workspace programmatically,

in other words the actions that is done by "File-Import-Existing code as makefile project" i want to do programmatically.

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Please don't just say something like: what's the code for this App/Plugin idea?

Comment: Is .project file created by the external tool?

Comment: well, the project files are created by an external tool. I dont see a .project file in the list of files generated.  just the makefile and the headers and cpp files.

my problem is i need to import this project using "import - makefile c project" into the workspace programmatically

Comment: Updated the question with a lot more clarity

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/ui/wizards/NewMakeProjFromExisting.java#n68) is the implementation of the "Import existing code as makefile project" action in the CDT source code.

I *think* what causes the `.cproject` file to be created is the `creatProjectDescription()` and `setProjectDescription()` calls, but I'm not 100% sure.